# Can I queue multiple items from a single run of an Azure Function?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage-queues, azure-functions

I have a Node.js `timerTrigger` Azure function that processes a collection and queues the processing results for further processing (by a Node.js `queueTrigger` function).

The code is something like the following:

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    collection.forEach(function (item) {
        var items = [];

        // do some work and fill 'items'

        var toBeQueued = { items: items };

        context.bindings.myQueue = toBeQueued;
    });

    context.done();
};
```

This code will only queue the last `toBeQueued` and not each one I'm trying to queue.

Is there any way to queue more than one item?

**Update**

To be clear, I'm talking about queueing a `toBeQueued` in each iteration of `forEach`, not just queueing an array. Yes, there is an issue with Azure Functions because of which I cannot queue an array, but I have a workaround for it; i.e., `{ items: items }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet, but we'll address that within the week, stay tuned :) You'll be able to pass an array to the binding as you're trying to do above.

We have an issue tracking this in our public repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/215). Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for referring me to the repository in GitHub. I guess we are talking about 2 different issues, am I right? I update the question to clarify this point.

Comment: I see the distinction. For Node.js after the above array fix, that array of messages is processed only **after** your function returns. I.e. no actual message queueing happens until your function is done. I think that will address the most common scenarios. Regarding your workaround above for queueing an array - that doesn't result in multiple individual queue messages being written. The array support is for scenarios where you need multiple individual messages to be enqueued.

Comment: Yeah, understood.. and like you said, I used the workaround only to address the array issue. So back to my question, the scenario that I'm trying to achieve isn't supported, (1) will it be?, and (2) what are my options?

Comment: Can you explain your scenario more? You're saying that you need the actual queue message to be enqueued on each loop iteration, as opposed to collecting all the messages in a single array, with the runtime enqueueing them for you one by one after your function returns? If so, can you explain why?

Comment: Before I explain why, the sentence "the runtime enqueueing them for you one by one after your function returns" caught my eye :) after [the coming fix](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/215), if I queued an array, will it be a single message queued and it happened to be an array (instead of a single object), or will each item in the array be a separate message in the queue? If the latter, you solved my problem, otherwise, I'll explain my scenario :)

Comment: It will be the latter :)

Answer (score 4):

Mathewc's answer is the correct one wrt Node.

For C# you can today by specifying `ICollector<T>` as the type of your output queue parameter.

Below is an example I have of two output queues, one of which I add via a for loop.

```
public static void Run(Item inbound, DateTimeOffset InsertionTime, ICollector<Item> outbound, ICollector<LogItem> telemetry, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {inbound}");

    telemetry.Add(new LogItem(inbound, InsertionTime));

    if(inbound.current_generation < inbound.max_generation)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < inbound.multiplier; i++) {
            outbound.Add(Item.nextGen(inbound));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And there's also an IAsyncCollector<T> with AddAsync().